# Coordinate geometry circle inscribed in triangle.

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

The circle $$x^2 +y^2 -4x-4y+4=0$$ is inscribed in a triangle which has two of its sides along the coordinate axes. How can we find the equation of the third line.

Now I have assumed that the line's equation would be

$${x \over a} + { y \over b} =1$$ where $a$ serves as the x intercept and $b$ as the y intercept.

[image]

Now since this line would be a tangent the perpendicular distance of the line from the centre of the circle would be equal to the radius of the circle.

Perpendicular distance from $(2,2)$ to $bx+ay=ab$:

$${|2b+2a-ab| \over \sqrt{b^2 +a^2}} = 2$$

This gives me one equation with two variables. How can I find other equations in order to solve this system? 
ANY HINT WOULD WORK.

Comment: There are infinitely such lines. This is the only equation possible. You can see this geometrically by creating some tangents of this circle. The tangents will meet both axes sometime

Comment: @N.S. John. Not all tangents will meet with both axes. e.g. x= 4 or y=4. Also for certain points the tangents will not cross the positive axes.

Comment: @MrYouMath sure thanks for adding that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As N.S.JOHN points out in his comment, there are an infinite number of such lines. If you parameterize the circle as $x=2+2\cos t$, $y=2+2\sin t$, then $\mathbf n=(\cos t,\sin t)$ is a normal to the circle at $(x(t),y(t))$, and an equation of the tangent at this point is $$\mathbf n\cdot(\mathbf x-(2,2))=(x-2)\cos t+(y-2)\sin t=2.$$ This line, together with the coordinate axes, will form a circumscribed triangle for $0\lt t\lt\pi/2$.

Answer (score 0):

That's the only equation you can get, because there are infinitely many lines that are possible. The only other condition is that the line must be a descending line in the first quadrant. In other words, $a,b>0$.

You can see that for any $a>4$, you can find a $b>0$ such that the condition will be satisfied.